# Read multiple lines from console

Tags: perl

How to read multiple lines from console in Perl?

I have used `@a = <STDIN>`; but I am unable to come out of that statement. Evertime I hit enter it goes to new line. I have read to hit `ctrl+d` to end the input but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Hit `Ctrl + d` on an empty line, or hit it twice. On MSWin, `Ctrl + z` is used.

Comment: The notation you used means 'read until EOF', so you will have to provide an EOF indication, and that means typing control-D or control-Z on an empty line or typing the character twice on a non-empty line.  If you don't want to 'read until EOF', use a different way of reading the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `while` loop,

```
my @a;
while (<STDIN>) {
    /\S/ or last; # last line if empty
    push @a, $_;
}

print @a;
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a better idea would be a loop of some sort:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a;
for(;;) {
    my $input = <STDIN>;
    last if not defined $input;
    chomp $input;
    push @a, $input;
}
```

This will end when you type in the Unix `<EOF>` (which is usually set to `Ctrl-D` by default).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are on Windows. On Windows you have to hit **Control-z** on an **empty line** and then hit **Enter.**