# How can I open and edit files through Perl?

Tags: file, perl, editing

I want to give the user input (multi-line) and print the multi-line output to a new file named by the user with

I've already tried

```perl
say "enter filename";
chomp(my $filename = <STDIN>);
open my $fn, '>', $filename;
say "enter contents";
print "> ";
chomp(my $contents = <STDIN>);
print {$fn} $contents;
close $fn;
```

but that only works with one line.

```perl
say "enter filename";
chomp(my $filename = <STDIN>);
open my $fn, '>', $filename;
say "enter contents";
print "> ";
chomp(my $contents = <STDIN>);
print {$fn} $contents;
close $fn;
```

but multi-line and creates a new file, not edits an old one

It either doesn't create a file, doesn't edit a file, or just doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Note your two snippets are identical. Maybe delete one to avoid confusion? What do you mean by "multi-line" ? What do you mean by "edit a file" ?

Comment: I mean so that the user can edit the file through Perl, and include more than 1 line in the output.

Comment: **Sorry for being so hard to understand ._.**

Comment: By edit a file, I mean create a file, ask the user what to call it, open it, ask the user what to put in it, print the user input to the .txt file, and save it. By multi-line, I mean the user should be able to put more than one line of text in the file.

Comment: You meant to say `print {$fn} $contents`, not `print {$filename} $contents`. `$filename` is a string but `$fn` is the file handle.

Comment: @MrMister So you want to use a loop with a prompt for each line to put in the file, and the line is appended at the end of the file? The user exits the loop by pressing some escape code?

Comment: Exactly @HåkonHægland

Comment: @mob, that was an accident while rewriting the code for the post, I got it right in the actual Perl file. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read multiple lines from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337582/read-multiple-lines-from-console)

Answer (score 2):

To type out a new file or add lines to an existing one

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $filename = shift;  # Better use a module (eg. Getopt::Long)

if (not $filename) { 
    $filename = get_filename();
}
elsif (-f $filename) {
    say "Appending to file \"$filename\".";
}
elsif (-e $filename and not -f $filename) {
    say "The \"$filename\" exists but is not a plain file.";
    $filename = get_filename();
}
else {
    say "Creating file \"$filename\"";
}

open my $fh, '>>', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
say "\nEnter lines to add. Press Ctrl-D when done.\n";

print ">  ";
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    print $fh $line;
    print ">  ";
}  

sub get_filename {
    print "Enter the name for a file to create/edit:  ";
    chomp (my $filename = <STDIN>);
    while (-e $filename and not -f $filename) { 
        say "The \"$filename\" exists but is not a plain file.";
        print "Enter the name for a file to create/edit:  ";
        chomp ($filename = <STDIN>);
    }   
    usage() if not $filename;
    return $filename;
}
sub usage { 
    say STDERR "Usage: $0 [filename]";
    exit;
}
```

Note that the actual writing of user's input can be written simply as

```
 print $fh $_ while <STDIN>;
```

All the rest is management of user input, checking etc.  That can be organized in many ways, depending on details of possible uses.  The above is a simple take, please change and tweak as suitable.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! You are my savior, @zdim.

Comment: @MrMister Well, I'm glad you like it :).  I edited, made the sub a little more robust.

Comment: @MrMister - You should consider [accepting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that lets you exit the loop by pressing CTRL-C:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

STDOUT->autoflush(1);
say "enter filename";
chomp(my $filename = <STDIN>);
open my $fh, '>', $filename or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";
{
    local $SIG{INT} = sub { die "SIGINT" };
    say "enter contents (CTRL-C to exit)";
    eval {
        while (1) {
            print "> ";
            my $contents = <STDIN>;  # do not need chomp here
            print $fh $contents;
        }
    };
    close $fh;
    say "\nDone. Saved file '$filename'";
}
```